# Command object only in controller or could it be passed to service layer?

Tags: grails, command-objects

In Grails framework I saw the command object pattern but its use is not very clear for me. In addition most of examples given by Grails documentation are about domain classes not command objects (maybe to simplify code example).

1 - Command object is something used between view and controller layer and must stay there ?

2 - Or is it a good practice to pass command object to service layer ?

To illustrate point 2 :

```
class MyController {

    def updateUserPassword (UserPasswordCommand cmd) {
        ...
        myService.updatePassword(cmd)
        ...
    }
}
```

If point 2 is a bad practice, then how do you pass submitted data to the service layer ? Via domain class ?
**EDIT : Seems OK**

**[EDIT]**

If I use command object and not domain class what to do in this case :

```
def signup(UserCreateCommand cmd)
{
    if (!cmd.hasErrors()) {
            def userInstance = userService.signup(cmd)
        }
    }
    if (cmd.hasErrors()) {
        /* Stay on form in order to display errors */
        render(view:"/app/authentication/_signupForm", model:[userCreateCommand: cmd])
        return
    }
    ...
}
```

what happen if when user service transaction ends, there is an exception raided by database (because of flushing data not respecting schema constraints) ?

The problem in my point of view is that there are two queries :

Firstly - when call cmd.hasErrors() there is a persistent call for unique constraint on email for example

Secondly - when service transaction ends, there is a flush to DB (which result in one SQL insert in my case), and maybe raises an exception on column email which has unique constraint

Test cmd.hasErrors() doesn't prevent the case where DB raises a violated constraint unique exception or I'm wrong ?

Comment: It's a very good practice to send the command object to the service.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore thanks for your advice, I've edited my question and specify a particular case with command object and your advice will be interesting

Comment: I thought that the purpose of the command object was to do data binding and to wrap the http request into an object rather than the implicit params. In my mind the Service layer should not know about command objects but rather business entities which could be either your Domains or DTOS which are used by the dao layer to actually update entities. Imagine that Service layer being exposed and reused in the Enterprise by other clients those clients may not be a form therefore not have a Command available but they could probably call that Service by passing a User or UserDto. Any thoughts?

Comment: So in my command objects where I bind form data , I do validation through constraints block but I also provide a get method that makes/finds an entity out of the bound parameters so that in controller I do the following
myService.registerNewStudent(command.getStudent())
Instead of myService.registerNewStudent(command)
Is that a bad practice?

Comment: @Viriato I think you're right, the cleaner way is to pass domain classes or DTOs to service layer, as you do by something like myCommandObject.getMyDtoOrDomain().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the best way to pass request params to service layer. I have seen people passing params to service which is really a worst practice. Our controllers should be dump, Max 5-8 LOC in controller method is a guideline in my company.

Command object gives you so much power out of the box like validation, method etc.

Comment: Thanks Uday, I've edited my question with a specific case, if you have an advice on it it will be welcome

Answer (score 0):

Constraints like unique which needs to validated from database cannot be applied on command object. In this case you can use validator http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.1/ref/Constraints/validator.html.

You can also use importFrom constraint to have all the constraint form User domain to command object http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.1/guide/validation.html.

Comment: I've done this, but what if I validated my command object with cmd.hasErrors() return true (cmd.email ="abc@abc.fr"), but then when I decide to call userService.saveMyUser(cmd) an other user has just save in database the email abc@abc.fr. When my transaction will finish, the flush to database will probably throw an exception because I try  to insert abc@abc.fr but it is already in database. I hope my example is clear.

Comment: because there will have two queries to database, the first for unique:true on email, and the second at the end of the transaction when flushing user to database.

Comment: sorry I meant cmd.hasErrors() return false, and userService found errors

Comment: I've found what seems to me the best practice. I will post it when I have time to.